typescript - how to import as const or transform it programmatically
I have a package called package1 that is published on npm. It contains some ts files. One of them looks like:
declare const _default: {
    DAOFactory: {
        abi: ({
            inputs: never[];
            stateMutability: string;
            type: string;
            name?: undefined;
            anonymous?: undefined;
            outputs?: undefined;
        }
   }
}

in my package2,  I import it:
import data from 'package1`

data.DAOFactory.abi successfully prints the object.
The problem: i need to somehow make data.DAOFactory.abi imported as const, but typescript doesn't allow this. What could be done in the runtime code of package2 such that I transform it to as const ?

I'm not sure what it means to import something as const here. A const assertion only applies to a literal expression. But there are no literal expressions in your code, only a type declaration. Can you explain without using as const in the explanation? What type do you expect data to have? And why you do you "the runtime code"? TypeScript is gone at runtime; it's been erased completely upon compilation. Please [edit] to give details for exactly the behavior you're looking for.
